# curl: (23) Failed writing body (675 != 8240) why?

Tags: c, curl

i have  a problem with curl curl, i want take a result of shell command (is  very long result ) the  curl command  is

```
curl -H "X-MBX-APIKEY: --- MY API KEY HERE ---"   -X 'GET' 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/historicalTrades?symbol=BNBUSDT&limit=500'
```

if  i run this command by shell work perfect , but if i run it by curl return
this is my code curl: (23) Failed writing body (675 != 8240),  why ?

```
    if (RING_API_PARACOUNT != 1) {
            RING_API_ERROR(RING_API_MISS1PARA);
            return;
        }
        if ( ! RING_API_ISSTRING(1) ) {
            RING_API_ERROR(RING_API_BADPARATYPE);
            return;
        }
    const char *UrlSpec = "/trades";
    const char *SymbolSqUry = "?symbol=";
    const char *SymblSQry = RING_API_GETSTRING(1);   
    const char *SymbolCloseQry = "&limit=";
    const char *miniCanapini = "\'";
    char CrossSymbl[20] = {0};
    char CossLmt[10] = {0};
    char *result;
    FILE *read_fp;
    char buffer[BUFSIZ +1];
    int chars_read;
    memset(buffer, '\0',sizeof(buffer));
    sscanf(SymblSQry,"%[a-zA-Z ];%[0-9 ]",CrossSymbl ,CossLmt);
    size_t sz = strlen(cmDOriG)  + strlen(OptioNncURL_g) +strlen(OptioNncURL_GET) + strlen(miniCanapini) + strlen(UrlApi)+ strlen(UrlApiV3) + strlen(UrlSpec) + strlen(SymbolSqUry) \
                + strlen(CrossSymbl)  +strlen(SymbolCloseQry)+strlen(CossLmt) + strlen(miniCanapini)   + 1;
    char destination[sz];
    strcpy(destination, cmDOriG);
    strcat(destination, OptioNncURL_g);
    strcat(destination, OptioNncURL_GET);
    strcat(destination, miniCanapini);
    strcat(destination, UrlApi);
    strcat(destination, UrlApiV3);
    strcat(destination, UrlSpec);
    strcat(destination, SymbolSqUry);
    strcat(destination, CrossSymbl);
    strcat(destination, SymbolCloseQry);
    strcat(destination, CossLmt);
    strcat(destination, miniCanapini);
    const char* mode = "r";
    read_fp=popen(destination, mode);
    if (read_fp != NULL)
       {
              chars_read = fread(buffer,sizeof(char),BUFSIZ,read_fp);
              if (chars_read > 0)
              {
              }
              pclose(read_fp);
       }          
    RING_API_RETSTRING(buffer);
```

Comment: You should probably consider using `libcurl` instead of shelling out to `curl`...

Comment: i dont  wanna use libcurl  thanks  again

Comment: Since you're apparently working with Ring, why not use the Ring libcurl bindings? You're just doing way too much work here for no good reason. https://ring-lang.sourceforge.io/doc1.3/libcurl.html

Comment: because ring  is new language , i tryed to use libcurl , but  for me  is very complicated and exist  only some  example ,  i prefer call diectly curl, (and i belive is also much faster then call libcurl by ring )

Comment: Unfortunately I believe you're wrong. Using the library will likely be faster than the overhead of spawning a new process and dealing with it.

Answer (score 3):

You're only reading a buffer of size `BUFSIZ` once.

It's unlikely that that single read, no matter how large `BUFSIZ` is, happens to be able to read the entire response as it's being output by curl.

You'll need to change the reading to a loop instead, that reads until the writing process is done.

Something like the below (but beware of off-by-one errors, I didn't double-check my math):

```
char buffer[BUFSIZ + 1] = {0};
int chars_read = 0;
FILE *read_fp = popen("foof", "r");
while (chars_read < BUFSIZ) {
  int nread =
      fread(buffer + chars_read, sizeof(char), BUFSIZ - chars_read, read_fp);
  if (nread == 0) {
    pclose(read_fp);
    break;
  }
  chars_read += nread;
}
// at this point, buffer is filled up to `chars_read` bytes
```

But better yet, use `libcurl`, the library version of cURL, instead of shelling out to the program. (For instance, I don't see you quoting any of those arguments, so you're vulnerable to shell injection attacks here.)

Comment: you have some example for  reads until the writing process is done. ?  thnks

Comment: I added an example that may or may not work for you.

Comment: thanks  so much for  example  but  do the  same  effect  , but if  the  buff  size is not  a problem  but  the  buffer  size  problem is  buffer  that  use a  function fread?? is possible modify the  buffer size of  fread?

Comment: How large is `BUFSIZ`? You will need enough memory for the entire response, of course, so either preallocate a large enough buffer or grow a buffer using e.g. `realloc`...

Comment: i use #define BUFSIZE 2097152   , but not change nothing  always  stamp  tha  same  content , i think a  problem is in fread??  bho

Comment: You say you define `BUFSIZE` (with an E), but your code uses `BUFSIZ` (no E). Do note that [`BUFSIZ` is _also_ an internal constant](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/BUFSIZ/) (and on my compiler its value is 8192).

Comment: o thanks  i notice  this  mistake  , but  not  work , but if  i #undef before  # def  it  work good   , thanks  next  question  is and  if  i dontknow  before  the  dimention of  buffer?? exist a  commando or  somthing similar?   thanks at  all

Comment: You will need to use eg malloc and realloc to manage memory allocation, or just allocate "more than enough" and hope for the best. (If you were using libcurl, you could get the response size as a header before receiving the body data.)